# Do any Christian traditions assert that there can be more than one "messiah"?

Tags: denomination-survey, messiah

Do any Christian traditions assert that there can be more than one messiah? Does the term 'messiah' as carried over from Hebrew thought come to mean a singular entity, utterly unique or is this a term that can be more loosely used to describe a plurality of entities.

How essential is singularity in the meaning of 'messiah' as understood through the full messianic concept held among Christian traditions? Are there cases where a Christian tradition speaks of multiple 'messiahs'?

Comment: You've got two quite different questions here which need to be asked separately: the grammar of the Hebrew, and what beliefs Christians believe. The first question isn't really on topic here. The second needs to be more specific too: do you just mean anyone who is anointed (which would include all of the kings and prophets) or do you mean the full messianic concept which arose after the completion of the Hebrew Bible?

Comment: Thanks @curiousdannii, I have edited the question as you suggested.

Comment: This still seems to be two separate questions, at least to me. Most Christians (at least of a scholarly stripe) recognize that the word "messiah," meaning anointed one, has referred to many people, while Jesus is the capital-M "Messiah" about whom the rest were mere [types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typology_(theology)) or [shadows](http://biblehub.com/colossians/2-17.htm). Are you asking about *that*, or are you asking whether any traditions believe that Jesus is the Messiah without being the *only* capital-M Messiah?

Answer (score 1):

The English word "messiah" is a loanword derived from the Latin word *[messias](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=messias&la=la#Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=Messias-contents)*, which itself is a transliteration of the Greek word [μεσσίας](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=G3323&t=KJV) (cp. [John 1:41](https://www.blueletterbible.org/kjv/jhn/1/41/t_conc_998041), [4:25](https://www.blueletterbible.org/kjv/jhn/4/25/t_conc_1001025)), which itself is a transliteration of the Hebrew word [מָשִׁיחַ](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?strongs=H4899), which is accurately transliterated into English as *mashiach*.

That being said, the Hebrew word מָשִׁיחַ is an adjective which translates into English as "anointed." As an adjective, it can also function as a substantive meaning "anointed one."

In the Bible, many people are referred to as מָשִׁיחַ, including priests ([Lev. 4:3](https://www.blueletterbible.org/kjv/lev/4/3/t_conc_94003)), prophets ([1 Kings 19:16](https://www.blueletterbible.org/kjv/1ki/19/16/t_conc_310016)), the kings of Israel ([1 Kings 19:16](https://www.blueletterbible.org/kjv/1ki/19/16/t_conc_310016)), and even the king of Persia ([Isa. 45:1](https://www.blueletterbible.org/kjv/isa/45/1/t_conc_724001)). Hence, we encounter the phrase הַכֹּהֵן הַמָּשִׁיחַ (*ha-kohen ha-mashiach*), or "the anointed priest" ([Lev. 4:3](https://www.blueletterbible.org/kjv/lev/4/3/t_conc_94003)).

It is thus evident that there were many "anointed ones," or as you put it, "messiahs." Even the Tanakh mentions many "anointed ones" ("messiahs") in one verse. For example,

In [1 Chr. 16:22](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt25a16.htm#22), it is written,

> Do not touch My anointed ones; do not harm My prophets.
>
> אַל תִּגְּעוּ בִּמְשִׁיחָי וּבִנְבִיאַי אַל תָּרֵעוּ

ִּבִּמְשִׁיחָי is not "My anointed one," for that would have been written בִּמְשִׁיחִי. The word בִּמְשִׁיחָי is plural, meaning "My anointed ones."

Furthermore, all Christians today are anointed and technically "messiahs."

> Now He who establishes us with you in Christ, and has **anointed us**, is God. <sub>[1 Cor. 1:21](https://www.blueletterbible.org/kjv/2co/1/21/t_conc_1079021)</sub>

Also,

> But **you have an anointing** from the Holy One, and you know everything. <sub>[1 John 2:20](https://www.blueletterbible.org/kjv/1jo/2/20/t_conc_1161020)</sub>

And,

> And the **anointing which you have received** from Him abides in you, and you have no need for anyone to teach you, but as the same anointing teaches you about everything, and is truth, and is no lie, even as it has taught you, you shall abide in Him. <sub>[1 John 2:27](https://www.blueletterbible.org/kjv/1jo/2/27/t_conc_1161027)</sub>

However, there is one anointed one who is the anointed par excellence (κατ' εξοχήν), and that is who Christians identify as the Lord Jesus Christ (i.e., Lord Jesus, the Anointed One). The reason the Lord Jesus is the Anointed One par excellence is because he was anointed with the "oil of gladness" more than any of his brothers. This "oil of gladness," which he was not given by measure ([John 3:34](https://www.blueletterbible.org/kjv/jhn/3/1/t_conc_1000034)), is the Holy Spirit (cp. [Acts 10:38](https://www.blueletterbible.org/kjv/act/10/38/t_conc_1028038)).

> <sup>6</sup> O' God, Your throne is for ever and ever. The sceptre of Your kingdom is a right sceptre. <sup>7</sup> You loved righteousness and hated wickedness. Therefore O' God, your God anointed you with the oil of gladness more than your fellows. <sub>[Psa. 45:6-7](https://www.blueletterbible.org/kjv/psa/45/6/t_conc_523006)</sub>

Hence, we call the Lord Jesus "the messiah" and not "a messiah."

Comment: This is an excellent explanation of the word Messiah, but it doesn't answer the question of whether any Christian traditions believe there might be more than one.

Comment: Will edit. Ran out of time unfortunately.